# "e-mail me" or "e-mail to me"?

Tags: grammar

What is the correct way to direct a request:

"Would you please **e-mail me** the check?"

or

"Would you please **e-mail to me** the check?"

And why?

Comment: Related/ Possible Duplicate. There are at least two previous posts dealing with this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"E-mail me the check" sounds right to me, and "e-mail to me the check" does not.  "E-mail the check to me" however, does sound correct.  This is typical of [ditransitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb) verbs in English: there is a choice between "me" as a direct object (without a preposition) and an indirect object (with a preposition), but the choice is often dictated by things like word order and whether or not the objects are pronouns.

Comment: Well, aside from the minor detail that a check, being a physical object, cannot be emailed, regardless of the grammar...

Comment: Indeed.  Note that if you swapped the order of the objects, it would be "e-mail the check to me" instead of "e-mail the check me"

Comment: @Marthaª One meaning of "check" is a bill (in particular, a restaurant one), which certainly can exist in a digital-only, emailable form.